# Tips to optimize query, with many subqueries in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have ~6 tables where I have to count or sum fields based on matching site_ids and date. I have the following query, with many subqueries which takes an extraordinary amount of time to run. I am certain there is an easier, more efficient way, however I am rather new to these more complex queries. I have read regarding optimizations, specifically using joins ON but struggling to understand and implement.

The goal is to speed this up and not bring my small server to it's knees when running. Any assistance or direction would be VERY much appreciated!

```
SELECT date(date_added) as dt_date,
       site_id as dt_site_id,
       (SELECT site_id from branch_mappings bm WHERE mark_id_site = dt.site_id) as site_id,
       (SELECT parent_id from branch_mappings bm WHERE mark_id_site = dt.site_id) as main_site_id,
       (SELECT corp_owned from branch_mappings bm WHERE mark_id_site = dt.site_id) as corp_owned,
       count(id) as dt_calls,
       (SELECT count(date_submitted) FROM mark_unbounce ub WHERE date(date_submitted) = dt_date AND ub.site_id = dt.site_id) as ub,
       (SELECT count(timestamp) FROM mark_wordpress_contact wp WHERE date(timestamp) = dt_date AND wp.site_id = dt.site_id) as wp,
       (SELECT count(added_on) FROM m_shrednations sn WHERE date(added_on) = dt_date AND sn.description = dt.site_id) as sn,
       (SELECT sum(users) FROM mark_ga ga WHERE date(ga.date) = dt_date AND channel LIKE 'Organic%' AND ga.site_id = dt.site_id) as ga_organic
FROM mark_dialogtech dt
WHERE site_id is not null
GROUP BY site_name, dt_date
ORDER BY site_name, dt_date;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appreciate all the responses.

I ended up creating a python script to run the queries separately and inserting the results into the table for the respective KPI. So, I scrapped the idea of a single query due to performance. I concatenated each date and site_id to create the id, then leveraged an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE with each INSERT statement.

The python dictionary looks like this, and I simply looped. Again, thanks for the help.

SELECT STATEMENTS (Python Dict)

```
"dt":"SELECT date(date_added) as dt_date, site_id as dt_site, count(site_id) as dt_count FROM mark_dialogtech WHERE site_id is not null GROUP BY dt_date, dt_site ORDER BY dt_date, dt_site;",
"ub":"SELECT date_submitted as ub_date, site_id as ub_site, count(site_id) as ub_count FROM mark_unbounce WHERE site_id is not null GROUP BY ub_date, ub_site;",
"wp":"SELECT date(timestamp) as wp_date, site_id as wp_site, count(site_id) as wp_count FROM mark_wordpress_contact WHERE site_id is not null GROUP BY wp_date, wp_site;",
"sn":"SELECT date(added_on) as sn_date, description as sn_site, count(description) as sn_count FROM m_shrednations WHERE description <> '' GROUP BY sn_date, sn_site;",
"ga":"SELECT date as ga_date, site_id as ga_site, sum(users) as ga_count FROM mark_ga WHERE users is not null GROUP BY ga_date, ga_site;"
```

INSERT STATEMENTS (Python Dict)

```
"dt":f"INSERT INTO mark_helper_rollup (id, on_date, site_id, dt_calls, added_on) VALUES ('{dbdata[0]}','{dbdata[1]}',{dbdata[2]},{dbdata[3]},'{dbdata[4]}') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dt_Calls={dbdata[3]}, added_on='{dbdata[4]}';",
"ub":f"INSERT INTO mark_helper_rollup (id, on_date, site_id, ub, added_on) VALUES ('{dbdata[0]}','{dbdata[1]}',{dbdata[2]},{dbdata[3]},'{dbdata[4]}') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ub={dbdata[3]}, added_on='{dbdata[4]}';",
"wp":f"INSERT INTO mark_helper_rollup (id, on_date, site_id, wp, added_on) VALUES ('{dbdata[0]}','{dbdata[1]}',{dbdata[2]},{dbdata[3]},'{dbdata[4]}') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE wp={dbdata[3]}, added_on='{dbdata[4]}';",
"sn":f"INSERT INTO mark_helper_rollup (id, on_date, site_id, sn, added_on) VALUES ('{dbdata[0]}','{dbdata[1]}',{dbdata[2]},{dbdata[3]},'{dbdata[4]}') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE sn={dbdata[3]}, added_on='{dbdata[4]}';",
"ga":f"INSERT INTO mark_helper_rollup (id, on_date, site_id, ga_organic, added_on) VALUES ('{dbdata[0]}','{dbdata[1]}',{dbdata[2]},{dbdata[3]},'{dbdata[4]}') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ga_organic={dbdata[3]}, added_on='{dbdata[4]}';",
```

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing is the equivalent of asking your server to query 7+ different tables every time you run this query. Personally, I use Joins and nested queries because I can whittle down do what I need.

The first 3 subqueries can be replaced with...

```
SELECT date(date_added) as dt_date,
    dt.site_id as dt_site_id,
    bm.site_id as site_id,
    bm.parent_id as main_site_id,
    bm.corp_owned as corp_owned,
    
    
    FROM mark_dialogtech dt
        INNER JOIN branch_mappings bm
            ON bm.mark_id_site = dt.site_id
```

I'm not sure why you are running the last 3. Is there a business requirement? If so, consider how often this is to be run and when.

If absolutely necessary, add those to the joins like...

```
FROM mark_dialogtech dt
    INNER JOIN 
        (SELECT site_id, count(date_submitted) FROM mark_unbounce GROUP BY site_id) ub
            on ub.site_id = dt.site_id
```

This should limit the results to only records where the site_id exists in both the mark_dialogtech and mark_unbounce (or whatever table). From my experience, this method has sped things up.

Still, my concern is the number of aggregations you're performing. If they can be cached to a dashboard and pulled during slow times, that would be best.

Comment: The reason for the aggregate of mark_unbounce, mark_wordpress_contact, m_shrednations and mark_ga  tables based on site_id and dates is to have totals in one place with the respective counts/sum of leads for a given date and site. I have considered splitting this up and producing separate queries, but was hoping to consolidate the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Its hard to analyze how big is your query(no data examples) but in your case I hightly recommend to use CTE(Common Table Expressions). Check this :
https://www.sqlpedia.pl/cte-common-table-expressions/

CTEs do not have a physical representation in tempdb like temporary tables or tabular variables. CTE can be viewed as such a temporary, non-materialized view. When MSSQL executes a query and encounters a CTE, it replace the reference to that CTE with definition. Therefore, if the CTE data is used several times in a given query, the same code will be executed several times and MSSQL does not optimize it. Soo... it will work just for few data like you want to do.

Answer (score -1):

It would be very difficult to analyze the query with out the data, Any ways!

try joining the tables and group it, that should improve the performance

here is a left join sample

SELECT column names
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.common_column = table2.common_column;

check this for more detailed inform https://learnsql.com/blog/how-to-left-join-multiple-tables/